# How to properly read the body of an HttpRequest within an Action Filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to figure out how to get the text from `Body` within `HttpRequest` inside the `OnActionExecuted` method implemented for an `IActionFilter`.  I have done hours of searching online, and tried many of the different solutions proposed, but each and every time the string representation is empty.  To do a sanity check, I added the following to `Startup` within the `Configure` method:

```
applicationBuilder.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var initialBody = context.Request.Body;

    using var bodyReader = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body);
    var body = await bodyReader.ReadToEndAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(body);
    context.Request.Body = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body));
    await next.Invoke();
    context.Request.Body = initialBody;
});
```

and the output from this is correct.  But, if this same code is moved to the filter, either `IActionFilter` or `IAsyncActionFilter`, it no longer gets the body correctly.

This is the most recent version of the filter class that I am trying to use:

```
/// <summary>
/// A filter for catching and and logging errors.
/// </summary>
[PublicAPI]
public sealed class ErrorFilter : IActionFilter, IExceptionFilter
{
  ...

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception == null) return;

        LogException(context.Exception, context.HttpContext.Request);

        context.Result = new ErrorResult(context.Exception, context.Controller);
        context.Exception = null;
    }

  ...

    /// <summary>
    /// Logs the specified exception and request.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="exception">The exception.</param>
    /// <param name="httpRequest">The HTTP request.</param>
    private void LogException(Exception exception, HttpRequest httpRequest)
    {
        if (Logger.Value == null) return;

        httpRequest.EnableBuffering();
        httpRequest.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        
        using var reader = new StreamReader(httpRequest.Body, Encoding.UTF8);

        var message = $"Request URL: {httpRequest.GetEncodedUrl()}\n" +
                      $"Body: {reader.ReadToEndAsync().Result}\n" +
                      $"Headers:\n{string.Join("\n", httpRequest.Headers.Select(header => $"   Key: {header.Key}, Value: {header.Value}"))}\n" +
                      $"Stacktrace: {exception}";

        Logger.Value.LogError("{Message}", message);
    }
}
```

Some additional information about the project:

- It is running on .NET 5
- It is leveraging Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning 5.0.0

CLARIFICATION:

I am aware that this is not a good idea, but it is a business requirement.  Logging every body when an exception is thrown is a vulnerability that can lead to a DDOS.

Comment: as far as I've experienced, this is not always ensured. If the model binding is not occurred, you can read the request body fine in action filters. But if the model binding is performed, looks like the default binding process will clear the request body making the action filters afterward unable to read it. I don't see any reason to put the code in action filters instead of using middleware, unless you need some other info only available in action filters (but you should state that clearly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand from you question, you have a requirement in which you need to log the exceptions. Why you do not try this approach:

**Using `try/catch` block**

```
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            var requestBodyStream = new MemoryStream();
            await context?.Request?.Body.CopyToAsync(requestBodyStream);

            requestBodyStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            string body = await new StreamReader(requestBodyStream).ReadToEndAsync();
            requestBodyStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            context.Request.Body = requestBodyStream;
            try
            {
                await next();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //you have now access to body and exception and whatever you need
                LogError(body);
            }
        });
```

register the following middleware in `Configure` method of `Startup.cs`

**Using Filters**

However if you want to get the body in `ExceptionFilter` then some thing like the following approach could help:

In `Configure` method of `Startup.cs`:

```
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            var requestBodyStream = new MemoryStream();
            await context?.Request?.Body.CopyToAsync(requestBodyStream);

            requestBodyStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            string body = await new StreamReader(requestBodyStream).ReadToEndAsync();
            context.Items["body"] = body;
            requestBodyStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            context.Request.Body = requestBodyStream;
            
            await next();
        });
```

and `ErrorFilter` class should looks like this:

```
public class ErrorFilter : IExceptionFilter //and other interfaces as you need
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Items.TryGetValue("body", out object body);
    }
}
```

Comment: That second option is actually the only way I found to get it to work in the filter, but I was not sure if that was best practice.  I think that is what I will end up doing.

Comment: @Jedi_Maseter_Sam I my self recommend the first method, as you see they both are the same with a little differences, but the first way is simple and more readable.